# How to implement mysql order by in following situation

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

There are 2 tables - Person(personName, areaId, birthDate) and Area(areaId, areaCode). Now I want a list of persons with their areaCode in a manner such that the all the persons from an areaCode are listed together and the areaCode with the oldest person should be first areaCode to appear. How do I achieve this through mysql query?

I have tried using ORDER BY with multiple columns in vain.

```
SELECT P.personName, A.areaCode, P.birthDate
FROM Person P
JOIN Area A ON P.areaId = A.areaId
ORDER BY P.birthDate, A.areaCode
```

Suppose there are Area1 and Area2. Area2 has the oldest and newest born person. Therefore, Area2 records should appear first.

Update: I managed to solve this, but is there any way I can shorten this code.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
    A.areaCode,
    MIN(P.birthDate)
FROM Area A
JOIN Person P on P.areaId = A.areaId
GROUP BY A.areaCode
ORDER BY P.birthDate) T1
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
    P.personName,
    A.areaCode,
    P.birthDate
FROM Area A
JOIN Person P on P.areaId = A.areaId
ORDER BY P.createdTimestamp) T2 ON T1.barcode = T2.binId;
```

Comment: Please share you both table few data to clear your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with a subquery to get the earliest birthdate in each area code.

```
                       SELECT A.areaId, MIN(birthDate) earliestBirthDate
                         FROM Area A 
                         JOIN Person P ON A.areaId = p.areaId
                        GROUP BY A.areaId
```

You can try this subquery to convince yourself it yields exactly one row per areaId, showing the needed earliest birth date.

Then you JOIN the subquery to your detail query

```
SELECT P.personName, A.areaCode, P.birthDate
FROM Person P
JOIN Area A ON P.areaId = A.areaId
JOIN (
                       SELECT A.areaId, MIN(birthDate) earliestBirthDate
                         FROM Area A 
                         JOIN Person P ON A.areaId = p.areaId
                        GROUP BY A.areaId
     ) EARLY ON P.areaId = EARLY.areaID 
ORDER BY EARLY.earliestBirthDate, P.birthDate, A.areaCode
```

The trick is to use a subquery to make a *virtual table* so you can order on a column from that table.

**Pro tip**: If you find yourself using `SELECT DISTINCT` to retrieve detail data from tables, it's a caution flag. You may be doing something wrong.